# all possibilities of a small list from a superset in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this csv file in python, which can be read as a dataframe.

```
SHOP_ID, COST, ITEM
1, 2.00, A
1, 1.25, B
1, 2.00, C
1, 1.00, D
1, 1.00, "A,B"
1, 1.50, "A,C"
1, 2.50, "A,D"
```

Now suppose the user enters A,B,C,D then I want all the possible combinations of this input from the dataframe['ITEM']. Or shall I use any other datastructure.
eg for A,B,C,D --

```
combination1    A    B    C    D
combination2    A    A,B  A,C  A,D
combination3    A    B    A,C  A,D
combination4    A    B    C    A,D
combination5    A,B  A,C  A,D
```

Comment: It's not clear how do you want those permutations to be generated (i.e. what are the final result). It could help if you provide a complete permutations set for a smaller list (e.g. only 3 items). Also, take a look at [itertools module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) - there are some useful combinatorial functions in it (e.g. `permutations`

Comment: for C,B,D it will be = [ (C + B + D) , (C + A,B + A,D), (C + B + A,D) , (A,B + A,C + A,D)]  ... So you can see that each of the four element of the list has C,B & D.

Comment: So the resulting list will contain at least `C` `B` and `D`, possibly also other values?

Answer (score 0):

All possible combinations? If you have a large dataset there will be way too many. If you want to do it, it is doable, for example if you want to have it contains `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`:

```
In [8]:

df['ITEM']
Out[8]:
0        A
1        B
2        C
3        D
4    "A,B"
5    "A,C"
6    "A,D"
Name: ITEM, dtype: object
In [12]:

[item for item in itertools.combinations(df['ITEM'], 4) if set(''.join(item)).issuperset({'A','B','C','D'})]
Out[12]:
[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'C', '"A,D"'),
 ('A', 'B', 'D', '"A,C"'),
 ('A', 'B', '"A,C"', '"A,D"'),
 ('A', 'C', 'D', '"A,B"'),
 ('A', 'C', '"A,B"', '"A,D"'),
 ('A', 'D', '"A,B"', '"A,C"'),
 ('A', '"A,B"', '"A,C"', '"A,D"'),
 ('B', 'C', 'D', '"A,B"'),
 ('B', 'C', 'D', '"A,C"'),
 ('B', 'C', 'D', '"A,D"'),
 ('B', 'C', '"A,B"', '"A,D"'),
 ('B', 'C', '"A,C"', '"A,D"'),
 ('B', 'D', '"A,B"', '"A,C"'),
 ('B', 'D', '"A,C"', '"A,D"'),
 ('B', '"A,B"', '"A,C"', '"A,D"'),
 ('C', 'D', '"A,B"', '"A,C"'),
 ('C', 'D', '"A,B"', '"A,D"'),
 ('C', '"A,B"', '"A,C"', '"A,D"'),
 ('D', '"A,B"', '"A,C"', '"A,D"')]
```